# Google Apps Script: CopyTo from one tab to another tab when the data met criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to apps script as well as this community. I am facing problem with apps script when I want to copy data from one tab to another tab.

I would like to copy the row (not whole row A:Z but only A:F) when column F is remarked as "Closed", copy the row from leads tab to customers tab.

This is the script that I did but it did not work at all

```
*function copyRowsWithCopyTo() {
  let spreadSheet = spreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Leads');

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('test');

  sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(3,2));
}*
```

Anyone can help? Thank you :)

Comment: About your comment posted as an answer, I deeply apologize that my proposed answer was not useful. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. 1. I cannot understand `However, it is still not working.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? 2. I cannot understand `You may refer to the picture attached below. This is how the leads tab looks like: If let's say the leads is closed and become customer I want it to go to the new tab which I temporary named it as test now. I noticed there is a line from you with the filter r => r[5...]`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: 3. I cannot understand your sample image. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: From your question, I understood that you want to copy the values from "Leads" sheet to "test" when the column "F" has the value of "Closed". In this case, you want to copy the columns "A" to "F" to "B3" of "test" sheet. For this, I proposed an answer. From `However, it is still not working.`, as the additional question, can I ask you about whether my understanding of your question is correct? If I misunderstood your question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the values from "Leads" sheet to "test" when the column "F" has the value of `Closed`. In this case, you want to copy the columns "A" to "F" to "B3" of "test" sheet.

#### Modification points:

- I think that `spreadsheetApp` of `let spreadSheet = spreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` is `SpreadsheetApp`.
- `spreadsheet` of `let targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('test');` is not declaread. From your script, I thought that it's `spreadSheet`.
- When `getDataRange()` is used, all data range is retrieved. In this case, you can retrieve the range of `A1:F`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function copyRowsWithCopyTo() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Leads');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:F" + sourceSheet.getLastRow())
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('test');
  const values = sourceRange.getValues().filter(r => r[5] == "Closed");
  targetSheet.getRange(3, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- In your question, you say `copy the row from leads tab to customers tab`. But in your script, `test` is used as the destination sheet. So, I used `test` as the destination sheet. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

### Added:

From your following comment,

> I want to copy the data in column A:K from "Leads" to "test" when column L in "Leads" is "Closed". I have entered the modified script that you written, but it is not working. Can understand?

I understood as follows.

- You want to copy the values from "Leads" sheet to "test" when the column "L" has the value of `Closed`. In this case, you want to copy the columns "A" to "K" to "B3" of "test" sheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function copyRowsWithCopyTo2() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Leads');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:L" + sourceSheet.getLastRow());
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('test');
  const values = sourceRange.getValues().flatMap(r => r.pop() == "Closed" ? [r] : []);
  targetSheet.getRange(3, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

### Added

In your 1st question, you said as follows.

> I would like to copy the row (not whole row A:Z but only A:F) when column F is remarked as "Closed", copy the row from leads tab to customers tab.

And, your showing script is as follows.

```
function copyRowsWithCopyTo() {
  let spreadSheet = spreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Leads');

  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('test');

  sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(3,2));
}
```

When I proposed an answer for this your 1st question, you changed your question as follows.

> I want to copy the data in column A:K from "Leads" to "test" when column L in "Leads" is "Closed". I have entered the modified script that you written, but it is not working. Can understand?

So, I proposed a sample script to your 2nd question. When I proposed an answer for your 2nd quesiton, you said `it is not solved yet`. And you provide the sample Spreadsheet as follows.

- Input: "Leads" sheet.

  [image]
- Output: "IMM" sheet.

  [image]

When I saw your provided sample script, your input sheet "Leads" has the data of columns "A" to "L".

But when I saw your destination sheet "IMM", it seems that it is required to put the data from the cell "A2". This is different from `sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(3,2));` in your showing script. And also, it seems that you wanted to copy the columns "B", "C", "D", "I", "J", "K" from the columns "A:L" to the cell "A2" of the destination sheet. I think that this is the reason for your current issue of `it is not solved yet`.

As the result, I understood that you wanted to achieve the following situation.

**When you want to retrieve the values from columns "A" to "L", and by checking "Closed" of the column "L", you want to put the values of columns "B", "C", "D", "I", "J", "K" to the cell "A2" of the destination sheet.**

In order to achieve your final goal, please test the following sample script.

```
function copyRowsWithCopyTo3() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Leads');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:L" + sourceSheet.getLastRow());
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('IMM');
  const values = sourceRange.getValues().flatMap(([, b, c, d, , , , , i, j, k, l]) => l == "Closed" ? [[b, c, d, i, j, k]] : []);
  console.log(values)
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

When this script is run for your sample Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

Comment: @Jesling Saw Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand [your provided image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi4ky.png), because your image has no information about the rows and columns. If the most left column is column "A", "Close" is existing in the column "L". If my understanding is correct, this is different from your question. In this case, please modify `const values = sourceRange.getValues().filter(r => r[5] == "Closed");` to `const values = sourceRange.getValues().filter(r => r[11] == "Closed");` and test it again.

Comment: @Jesling Saw But, in the case of `const values = sourceRange.getValues().filter(r => r[11] == "Closed");`, the columns "A" to "F" are copied. This is from your question. Is this situation also different between your question and your expected result? I'm worried about this.

Comment: I want to copy the data in column A:K from "Leads" to "test" when column L in "Leads" is "Closed". 

I have entered the modified script that you written, but it is not working.

Can understand?

Comment: @Jesling Saw Thank you for replying. From your reply of `I want to copy the data in column A:K from "Leads" to "test" when column L in "Leads" is "Closed". I have entered the modified script that you written, but it is not working. Can understand?`, I understood that your posted question is different from your expected result. For this, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize again. By the way, please delete your answer posted as a comment.

Comment: @Jesling Saw Sorry. I updated my added script. Could you please confirm it again? The result is the same before and after updating.

Comment: Hey, you dont mind i add you into the sheet, then you help me to modify it or we can have a teamviewer in this case?

Comment: @Jesling Saw Thank you for replying. About `Hey, you dont mind i add you into the sheet, then you help me to modify it or we can have a teamviewer in this case?`, I think that this is a new question. In this case, first, how about resolving your this question? If my proposed answer didn't resolve your this question, I have to apologize. Can I ask you about whether my proposed answer could resolve your this question?

Comment: Nope, it is not solved yet :(

Comment: @Jesling Saw Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `Nope, it is not solved yet :(`, In my understanding of your question, you changed your 1st question. Your 2nd question is `You want to copy the values from "Leads" sheet to "test" when the column "L" has the value of Closed. In this case, you want to copy the columns "A" to "K" to "B3" of "test" sheet.`. My answer is to this your 2nd question. I tested my proposed script, I confirmed that your 2nd question can be resolved.

Comment: @Jesling Saw But you say `Nope, it is not solved yet :(`. In this case, it is required to confirm your current situation. So can you provide the detailed information of `Nope, it is not solved yet :(`? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your 2nd question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. You may refer to the file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tV1kk-B2RwiuxviGJtDeazVaUr6kmYg4RyHE42IQdYo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jesling Saw Thank you for replying. From your provided sample Spreadsheet, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? I could find that the reason of `it is not solved yet` is that your provided information is different from your sample Spreadsheet. I have to apologize that I couldn't notice this. So, I proposed a sample script using your provided Spreadsheet.

Comment: function copyRowsWithCopyTo3() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Leads');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:L" + sourceSheet.getLastRow());
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('IMM');
  const values = sourceRange.getValues().flatMap(([, b, c, d, , , , , i, j, k, l]) => l == "Closed" ? [[b, c, d, i, j, k]] : []);
  console.log(values)
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}

this?

Comment: @Jesling Saw Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply of `this?`, I cannot understand what you want to say. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, I'm continuing to answer to your various questions. But I noticed that you posted it as your new question. This is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: I got nothing to the IMM tab, you can refer to the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tV1kk-B2RwiuxviGJtDeazVaUr6kmYg4RyHE42IQdYo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jesling Saw Thank you for replying. I had already added a sample script for using your sample Spreadsheet. And also, I added a result situation as the image. Can you test my proposed script? If you cannot do it, I have to apologize again.

Comment: Tanaike, I tried but nothing show on the IMM tab. You may refer to the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tV1kk-B2RwiuxviGJtDeazVaUr6kmYg4RyHE42IQdYo/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Jesling Saw Thank you for replying. About `I tried but nothing show on the IMM tab. You may refer to the sheet`, when I tested your provided Spreadsheet inlcuding my proposed script, I cannot replicate your situation. The retrieved values are put to `the IMM tab`. So, how do you execute your script? And, can you provide the detailed flow for replicating your current situation? By this, I would like to check it.

Comment: Can we have a zoom call so that easy to show you. It is very hard to tell you the problem here. https://us04web.zoom.us/j/71859744443?pwd=y1eOev9A-1E37gY0gQUaIUBIUnypKj.1

Comment: @Jesling Saw Thank you for replying. About `Can we have a zoom call so that easy to show you. It is very hard to tell you the problem here.`, I cannot use it. I apologize for this. Can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I go Extension >> Apps Script >> copy and paste the script >> Save 

but nothing show in the IMM. You can help me to run this on the sample file?

Comment: @Jesling Saw Thank you for replying. From `I go Extension >> Apps Script >> copy and paste the script >> Save but nothing show in the IMM.`, in this case, it seems that you don't execute your script. Please run the function with the script editor? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/automation#try_it_out) By this, the script is executed. When you run the script for the first time, a dialog for authorizating scopes is opened. At that time, please permit them.

Comment: I got the TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined on this line >> let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:L" + sourceSheet.getLastRow());

Comment: @Jesling Saw Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `I got the TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined on this line >> let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:L" + sourceSheet.getLastRow());`. When I tested your provided sample Spreadsheet including my script, no error occurs. So can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy Row with formats

```
function copyRows() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sh0 = ss.getSheetByName('Leads');
  let rg0 = sh0.getRange("A1:F" + sh0.getLastRow())
  let tsh = ss.getSheetByName('test');
  const values = rg0.getValues().forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[5] == "Closed") {
      sh.getRange(i+1,1,1,6).copyTo(tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1));
    }
  });
}
```