# Google Apps Script [Copy Data from one tab to another tab]

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a leads tracker file where for sales to track. There are 2 tabs which are "Leads" and "IMM". I want the certain columns of data from Leads when it is CLOSED copy to IMM

You may refer to the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tV1kk-B2RwiuxviGJtDeazVaUr6kmYg4RyHE42IQdYo/edit?usp=sharing

Anyone can help me out with the apps script?

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to do about your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71506703

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy Closed from Leads to IMM

```
 function lfunko1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Leads");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('IMM');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let d = 0;
  let o = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[11] == "Closed") {
      o.push([r[1],r[2],r[3],r[8],r[9],r[10]]);
      //sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++);//uncomment this if you wish to delete them
    }
  });
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Comment: Nothing is appear on the IMM :(

Comment: It is on my spreadsheet.  Also I updated the function selecting only the columns that you wanted